# What is the number of families that buy newspaper A only?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In a town of 10000 families it was found that 40% families buy newspaper A, 20% buy newspaper B, 10% buy newspaper C, 5% families buy both A and B, 3% families buy B and C, and 4 % buy A and C. If 2% families buy all the three newspapers, then what is the number of families that buy only newspaper A?

Why is it wrong when I calculate A-(B U C) for the number of families that buy only newspaper A?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do A - (B U C) as not everyone in B U C bought newspaper A.

Instead I suggest you make a Venn diagram, then work out the bits to remove from A. Remember that you csn only remove people from the set if they are currently in it!

You can start by removing people who bought both A and B, leaving 35%. Now remove people who bought both A and C, leaving 31%.

But wait! Anyone who bought all 3 papers has now been removed from the count twice. We'd better add them back in once. We're told that's 2%, so we get a total of 33% who bought only A and not B or C.

As I say, try drawing a Venn diagram and  crossing out areas as you remove them. Remember that when you're told that N people bought both A and B, this includes anyone who also bought C.